# Difficulty installing moderncv on OS X

Tags: installing, mactex, moderncv

I am trying to install the [moderncv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMhRg.png) package on my machine running Mac OS X 10.4.  Here is what I have done:

1. Ran this: 
   `% kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`which returned:
   `/Users/jsummers/Library/texmf`
2. Created the directory: `/Users/me/Library/texmf/tex/latex`
3. Downloaded `moderncv-0.12(2).zip` and extracted it into the above dir.
   [image]
4. I then ran `sudo texhash` to let tex know where the files are.
   [image]
5. Then I ran this to check if it is installed.  (Neither returned anything). 
   `% kpsewhich moderncv`
   `% kpsewhich moderncv.sty`

What am I missing here?  I have followed the directions on [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

Comment: It's a class file, how about `kpsewhich moderncv.cls`?

Comment: By the way, `moderncv` seems to be installed by default (I'm using TeXLive 2010), are you sure it isn't installed already?

Comment: @Juan.  You are right when I do `kpsewhich moderncv.cls` it is there.  It appears that I had a different error.  Do you want to put this as an answer and I will accept it?  I am using TeXLive 2009, which does not include moderncv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to tex-live 2010 and it worked.  I think that I just had tex live 2009basic installed which I assumed did not have `moderncv` installed.  I tried what Juan suggested but I think that I was missing to much other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The package `moderncv` comes in a class file, so you should be able to find it as

```
> kpsewhich moderncv.cls
```