# LaTeX Error: File `marvosym.sty' not found.

Tags: installing, errors

I am [trying to get moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/difficulty-installing-a-new-package) working.  I just installed it and `% kpsewhich moderncv.cls1` finds it.

When I compile this tex document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
```

(one line document).

I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `marvosym.sty' not found.
```

Do I need to install marvosym.sty?  Can I just drop it in:

```
/Users/me/Library/texmf/tex/latex/newFolder
```

Or do I need to install something else to get marvosym.sty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking from your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/difficulty-installing-a-new-package) you seem to have too many missing packages (I'm not sure but I think these *should* also be available in TeXLive 2009). If you're using [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/), there is an application “TeX Live Utility” which should be able to help you installing and updating packages.

If you keep running into problems it's probably a good idea to [upgrade your system to TeXLive 2010](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3311/how-to-upgrade-texlive-2009-to-texlive-2010).

Comment: where can I find the TeX live Utility?  Is it a command that I can call?  I have 2009basic installed.

Comment: which is your OS? If you're on a Mac, you're better off installing MacTeX with the *full* installation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had TeXLive 2009basic installed.  I upgraded to 2010 and that fixed up everything.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14):

For Debian/Ubuntu you can use

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

With a modern tex system (miktex, texlive) you can use the package managers to install the package. If you have an old system: marvosym has a documentation (marvosym.pdf) which has a section "installation" on the first page.

Comment: I think that I have texLive installed.  Where can I find the package manager?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm using miktex on a windows PC. But texlive has a documentation, if you don't find it on your PC try a google search for "texlive".